# Unity, проект не отображается на рабочем столе

Tags: unity3d

Создал новый проект для unity, но он не отображается на рабочем столе
При этом в строке приложений и в диспетчере задач он запущен
Проект стандартный, просто 2d (upr)
Путь к проекту не содержит русских символов
Версия 2022.3.21F1

[image: Запущенный проект]

Comment: А с чего он должен отображаться? Туда вставлен его ярлык?

Comment: Ну окно проекта разве не должно отображаться?
Просто через тот же alt Tab видно что проект запущен, но само окна проекта вывести я не могу

Comment: Вы, значит, не о том говорите. На рабочем столе отображается то, что туда вставили. В строке состояния (и при нажатии Alt+Tab, соответственно) отображается то, что запущено. охарактеризуйте проблему понятнее.

Comment: Проект запущен, он есть в строке снизу (запущенный) и при alt+Tab 
Но при этом при виборе данного окна, окно проекта не отображается